# Can't update existing records MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've created a new column (third one) and all records are `null` in that column. The table has 100 rows. When I try `INSERT INTO`, records are added but only from 101 row and previous ones are still `null`. That's why I decided to use `UPDATE`, but I have the next error message: `You can't specify target table 'actors' for update in FROM clause`

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE
    actors
SET
    starred_count = (
        SELECT COUNT(actors.Actor_id)
        FROM starred
        INNER JOIN actors ON actors.Actor_id = starred.Actor_id
        GROUP BY starred.Actor_id
        ORDER BY starred.Actor_id
    )
```

How could I do this properly?

Comment: You're setting every row's `starred_count` to the same value. You probably mean to do a multi-table update with a join clause.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the logic of the UPDATE, but have a look here at Derived Tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html.

Comment: I tried this solutions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/12737534) but result is still the same :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to next query, since on MySQL updating using a query is not valid.

```
UPDATE
    actors AS a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Actor_id, COUNT(*) AS starred_count
     FROM starred
     GROUP BY Actor_id) AS s ON s.Actor_id = a.Actor_id
SET
    a.starred_count = s.starred_count
```

Comment: Ohh it works. Now i have to carefully analyse my mistake.